# Service - убийство окна останавливает service

Tags: java, android, android-service

Пытаюсь создать службу-плеер "играть случайные аудио-файлы пользователя друг за другом". В целом весь код работает идеально (все проигрывается как нужно), но вот когда я убиваю Активити (именно убиваю, а не просто сворачиваю значком домой) через диспетчер окон - проигрывание останавливается

Мой сервис:

```
public class MusicServ extends Service {
    public MusicServ() {
    }

    MediaPlayer mus = new MediaPlayer(); 

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // тут проигрыватель MediaPlayer

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Вызываю его в MainActivity:

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicServ.class));
```

Comment: Видимо вы запускаете сервис в том же процессе. `android:process`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon т.е. про этот код можно забыть навсегда? он работает так как и должен, а то, что я хочу - это к oreground service ?

Comment: Для фоновой работы (например воспроизведение музыки) по любому нужен foreground service.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon а можно пример? это сам Service по другому пишется или только его вызов?

Comment: https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/, также, как сказал user7860670, поменяйте `android:process` в манифесте у сервиса

Comment: @user7860670 несовсем понял о чем вы

Comment: Надо поменять https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc чтобы сервис запускался в отдельном процессе.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon ваш пример помог. НО! `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)` будет ли он работать на старых телефонах?

Comment: На старых телефонах запускайте обычный сервис.

Comment: @Style-7 а "старые" это от какого API ? не с головы же брать уровень API

Comment: со строчки выше не догадались?

Comment: @Style-7 API 26 ? но я протестил на 22 и 23 - все работает и так.

Comment: startForegroundService появился с 26, о чем вы говорите?

Comment: @Style-7 о том, что хочу разобраться.  `compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion 28`. в коде используется ТОЛЬКО `СontextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), serviceIntent);` и это работает на телефонах API 25, 23, 22. отсюда и сообсна вопрос.

Comment: "будет ли он работать на старых телефонах" будет. Просто c api 26 доступны [NotificationChannel](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/515-urok-190-notifications-kanaly.html). Функция `СontextCompat.startForegroundService` специально и сделана для того, чтобы правильно запускать ForegroundService как на api < 26, так и на api >= 26, посмотрите код этой функции